# Order the Genders and Numbers

Tags: python, list

I need help ordering the list:

```
Tom,M,1658
Anthony,M,985
Lisa,F,8976
Ben,M,698
Shelly,F,8975
```

So I need help sorting the order from F to M then Smallest Numbers to Largest Numbers. The output should look like this:

```
Shelly,F,8975
Lisa,F,8976
Ben,M,698
Anthony,M,985
Tom,M,1658
```

So basically, females first then smallest to largest numbers, then male then smallest to largest. M = male, f=female.

This is what I have so far:

```
class names():
    pass
    #__slot__ == ('No', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Occurrences')

def mkEntry(textFileName):
    for currentFile in textFileName:
        print(currentFile.strip())

def main():
    openFile = 'yob' + input("Enter the year <Do NOT include 'yob' or .'txt' : ") + '.txt'
    textFileName = open(openFile)
    mkEntry(textFileName)

main()
```

I don't know where you go from there. I am bad at python.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort by second (F/M) and third (698, 985, 1558...) attribute.

```
import operator

lst = [
    ('Lisa', 'F', 8976),
    ('Shelly', 'F', 8975),
    ('Tom', 'M', 1658),
    ('Anthony', 'M', 985),
    ('Ben', 'M', 698)]
]   
sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you just need to skip element at 0 index of a tuple, 'F' goes before 'M', simple sorting will do the job:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[1:]))

# [
#    ('Shelly', 'F', 8975),
#    ('Lisa', 'F', 8976),
#    ('Ben', 'M', 698),
#    ('Anthony', 'M', 985),
#    ('Tom', 'M', 1658)
#]
```

or, if you need inplace sorting:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1:]))
```

Comment: Okay. `a` is a variable. Then what is `key=lambda`? I have never heard of that before. Mind explaining it? Thanks

Comment: The easiest way to understand a lambda is that it is a way to write a  function without using def or return.  You could also just have a normal function do the same thing, and have key=function_name